# What to input into the Glide's "with" when using together with Groupie?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-context, android-glide

I am using Lisa Wray's Groupie for my recycler view, that is hosted inside a fragment.

I've used it before succesfully with Picasso, but for various resons I would like to switch to Glide.

I am facing a block though, as I can't find what to place into the "with" part of Glide, been trying everything I can think of.

This is my Class I use for Groupie:

```
class FeedImage(val image: Images) : Item<ViewHolder>() {

    override fun getLayout(): Int {
        return R.layout.feed_single_photo
    }

    override fun bind(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        Glide.with(NOT_SURE_WHAT_TO_PLACE_HERE).load(image.image).into(viewHolder.itemView.feed_single_photo_photo)
    }
}
```

Comment: In the `with` method, context is passed as parameter. Have you tried `viewHolder.itemView.getContext()`?

Comment: Hey Rick thanks for your response. I've found the solution that wasn't exactly that but fairly similar. I've added it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this as the answer

```
Glide.with(viewHolder.root.context).load(image.image).into(viewHolder.itemView.feed_single_photo_photo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Full answer,

```
class FeedImage(val image: Images) : Item<ViewHolder>() {

    override fun getLayout() = R.layout.feed_single_photo

    override fun bind(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int)
    {
        viewHolder.itemView.apply {
            Glide.with(viewHolder.root.context)
                .load(image)
                .into(feed_single_photo_photo)
        }
    }
```